# Select change (not with "$(this).attr('value'))" but to trigger execution of another function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want trigger execution of another function from select change.

I want to trigger execution of updateFormats(); How to do this in jQuery?

```
$('#inproj').change(function(){
            updateFormats();
                });

$('#outproj').change(function(){
            updateFormats();
        });
```

The code below works for changing the value of all select. However, I want the inproj and outproj select to trigger the execution of updateFormats() mentioned above.

```
$("select").change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
          str += $(this).text() + " ";
                      });
                    $("div").text(str);
                      })
                     .change();
```

The HTML of select inproj and outproj (jquery-mobile);

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for="inproj" class="select">Input Projection:</label>
   <select name ="inproj" id="inproj">
       <option value="EPSG:4326" selected="selected">EPSG:4326</option>
       <option value="EPSG:900913">Spherical Mercator</option>
    </select> <br />
  </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <label for="outroj" class="select">Output Projection:</label>
       <select name="outproj" id="outproj">
      <option value="EPSG:4326" selected="selected">EPSG:4326</option>
      <option value="EPSG:900913">Spherical Mercator</option>
    </select> 
    <br />
        </div>
```

The updateFormats() function.

```
$(function() {
  function updateFormats() {
            var in_options = {
                'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection(OpenLayers.Util.getElement("inproj").value)
            };   
            var out_options = {
                'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection(OpenLayers.Util.getElement("outproj").value)
            };
            var gmlOptions = {
                featureType: "feature",
                featureNS: "http://example.com/feature"
            };
            var gmlOptionsIn = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, gmlOptions),
                in_options
            );
            var gmlOptionsOut = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, gmlOptions),
                out_options
            );

            var kmlOptionsIn = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                {extractStyles: true}, in_options);
            formats = {
              'in': {
                wkt: new OpenLayers.Format.WKT(in_options),
                geojson: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(in_options),
                georss: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoRSS(in_options),
                gml2: new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v2(gmlOptionsIn),
                gml3: new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3(gmlOptionsIn),
                kml: new OpenLayers.Format.KML(kmlOptionsIn),
                atom: new OpenLayers.Format.Atom(in_options)
              }, 
              'out': {
                wkt: new OpenLayers.Format.WKT(out_options),
                geojson: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(out_options),
                georss: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoRSS(out_options),
                gml2: new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v2(gmlOptionsOut),
                gml3: new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3(gmlOptionsOut),
                kml: new OpenLayers.Format.KML(out_options),
                atom: new OpenLayers.Format.Atom(out_options)
              } 
            };
        }
      });  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean like:

```
$('#inproj, #outproj').change(updateFormats);
```

that should trigger the function but you've put your function inside a `$(function(){...})` block which seems odd.

so try

```
$(function(){
    function updateFormats() {
        // updateFormats code here
    };
    $('#inproj, #outproj').change(updateFormats);
});
```

let me know any problems.

**Update**

here is an example of it working in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QV8gc/)

Comment: I tried solution 1. and remove the $function() {...}) in UpdateFormats. The OpenLayers Map canvas is not displaying, only the select controls and other. I doubt it is able to updateFormats as well. Solution 2. Select controls are not displaying after click it. I don't know if it executing the updateFormat function.

Comment: @ns-1 This is all one solution. try `$('#inproj, #outproj').change(function(){ alert("changed!");});` and let me know if you get an alert. Otherwise something else is wrong.

Comment: @ns-1m I also wanted to point out you have a typo in your label `for='outroj'` instead of `for='outproj'` in-case you missed that.

Comment: James, thanks for helping me solve this problem. However, I am not getting the alert that we are placing in updateFormats() function. It seems that jQuery does not like the DOM elements i.e. OpenLayers.Util.getElement("inproj").value) and OpenLayers.Util.getElement("outproj").value). It is not also giving back the select control. How we jQuerize the .getElement(..).value?

Comment: James, I found out that OpenLayers.Util.getElement function is equal to var $ in OpenLayers. I think this is the problem. Here is the link. http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/mapfish-openlayers-extjs-jquery-usage-problems-td2462410.html

Comment: It seems that it change. /** 
 * Maintain existing definition of $.
 */
if(typeof window.$  === "undefined") {
    window.$ = OpenLayers.Util.getElement;
}

Comment: You should use `jQuery` insead of `$`. i've had to do this before and maybe that will fix issues.